# How can i create a div which contains two divs and stretch automatically

Tags: css

Hi every one i'm trying to create two divs. One div has a different style as you can see below

```
#subpage_left
{
    width:167px;
    border:solid 2px red;
    background-image:url(../../images2/images/altsayfa_menu_bg.jpg); 
    background-repeat: repeat;

    float:left;
}
```

And the second one which displays the text that comes from my data

```
#subpage_right
{
    width:700px;
    background-color:White;
    border:solid 2px red;
    font-family: 'Museo300Regular';

    float:left;


}
```

I wanna place these divs side by side but my data comes to "subpage_right" div so this div stretch by text length and the "subpage_left" div does not stretch i mean these divs are not same height as you can see image

[image]

so i need a css like a wrapper that stretch these divs automatically but how can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can **display:table** property for this. Write like this:

```
#subpage_left,#subpage_right{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/9Eytv/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
#maincont
{
position:relative;
width: 867px; 
height: auto;}

#subpage_left
{
width:167px;
border:solid 2px red;
background-image:url(../../images2/images/altsayfa_menu_bg.jpg); 
background-repeat: repeat;
float:left;
}

#subpage_right
{
width:700px;
background-color:White;
border:solid 2px red;
font-family: 'Museo300Regular'; /* Use some standard font Like Arial */
float:left;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
```

And the div's

```
<div id="maincont">
<div id="subpage_left"></div>
<div id="subpage_right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this works for you :)